# Наследуется ли interface от System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Наследуется ли interface от System.Object?

Comment: это не связанные между собой понятия

Comment: А какая разница то Вам? Если инстанс Ваш всё равно будет наследоватся от Object (если Вы не пишете адские хаки на чистом IL)?

Comment: Ну и [вот ответ на Ваш вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236305/do-interfaces-derive-from-system-object-c-sharp-spec-says-yes-eric-says-no-re).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Нет.**

В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173156.aspx) говорится:

> Интерфейсы не содержат реализацию методов.

Если бы интерфейс каким-то образом наследовался от `System.Object`, он бы унаследовал реализацию его методов (например, `ToString()`), что противоречит документации.

Фактически в C# интерфейсы не считаются классами. Например, класс может *наследовать* только одному классу, но *имплементировать* при этом любое количество интерфейсов.

Comment: Видать вопрос вызван тем что можно написать `IDisposable d; d.(методы_object)`.. что вызывает легкое недоумение почему так? Но любой тип производный от любого интерфейса будет унаследован от `Object`.. может быть это не понял до конца автор :)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Думаю, что возможность такого вызова есть из-за неявной конверсии любого ссылочного типа в `object` (упоминается в ответе, на который давали ссылку в комментариях к вопросу).

Comment: @AntonKomyshan вообще, интерфейс это вполне так себе `тип`. Открытый тип, наряду с абстрактными классами и обобщениями. Но если задуматься о том, как устроены типы в CLR и где будет ссылка у типа на интерфейс (на его мету, заголовок и таблицу методов) то становится не всё так однозначно.

Comment: "неявной конверсии любого ссылочного типа в object" - да-да, я же тоже об этом) на первый взгляд на .net - это просто не очевидно: откуда студия выдает методы object'a на типе объявленного как интерфейс.

Comment: А есть методы явного запрета? Я конечно понимаю что есть code style относительно языка и ряд соглашений. А вдруг я дурачек и не вижу перед в названии первую букву `I` и хочу вызвать метод от object.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Не совсем понял, явного запрета чего именно?

Comment: @VladD вызова Object методов относительно интерфейса

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Я о таких методах не знаю, думаю, что нету.